# Membership: Resetting user password

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, asp.net-membership, web.config-transform

I'm using ASP.NET Membership (SQL Server) Provider to manage my users. For normal users, they need to use question/answer method to reset their password, so the `requiresQuestionAndAnswer` flag is `true` in `web.config`. But in the Admin section (which resides in a subfolder in the website), I need to enable password reset without requiring him to enter question's answer. So I tried to adding a separate `web.config` in the Admin subfolder, expecting it to inherit everything from the root folder by default, and then applied the following transform onto it, for both Debug and Release configurations:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.web>
        <membership>
            <providers>
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"              xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The `web.config` of the Admin subfolder itself is empty in the sense that it just contains
`<?xml version="1.0"?><configuration />`. Of course I expect it to inherit all other settings from the root folder's `web.config`. But it doesn't seem to work. `ResetPassword()` method of Membership still gives me `Value cannot be null` error when I try to call the parameter-less overload. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Figured it out. The approach I was taking was wrong. There's no need to setup another `web.config` in the Admin subfolder. You basically need to add a second MembershipProvider to your root level `web.config`, with a different name of course, and set `requiresQuestionAndAnswer` to `false` for it. In the `<membership>` node, you can set `defaultProvider="NAME_OF_YOUR_FIRST_PROVIDER"` to ensure security.

Then in your code, you can do the following to reset user's password without requiring question/answer thing.

```
 MembershipUser mu = Membership.Providers["NAME_OF_YOUR_SECOND_PROVIDER"].GetUser(<USERNAME>, false);
 if (mu != null)
     string NewPwd = mu.ResetPassword();
```